# Gulp useref generates empty file

Tags: html, css, gulp, gulp-useref

I have a gulp setup with useref to concatenate and minify my css files:

```
var gulpIf = require('gulp-if');
var useref = require('gulp-useref');
var cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');

gulp.task('useref', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/*.html')
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

My HTML file looks like:

```
<!-- build:css assets/css/theme.min.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/theme.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

package.json:

```
"gulp-useref": "^3.1.2",
```

When I do a new build, the `theme.min.css` gets created, however it is empty (while the original `theme.css` has something like 150Kb of styles). No error is thrown too. Any ideas?

Comment: I had to replace gulp-useref with gulp-useref-plus. However, I still have no idea what happened.